# Using JMS Topic on two different EAR on TEA

Tags: jms, tibco, ems

I've a question about Tibco TEA.
I've two project, HR and PP, where in HR there's a topic Receiver and in PP there's a Send topic.
I can't upload EARs from this projects on TEA because when I upload HR, a topic with a subscriber is created on JMS service; when I try to upload PP there's a error saying " you can upload this EAR because there's already a topic with the same client ID ".

I can't purge the topics all the time so maybe I'm doing wrong something ?

Answer (score 0):

AAANd the answer is ! Just create difference connector for each EAR project you want to create and set 'Autogenerate ID' just for the JMS Topic Sender. For the Receiver you have to create a jms connection with a name into the subrscriber section; with that, the topic isn't create automatically and the receive use always a differente name. So for 2 EAR project just create 4 jms connection at all.